# Stop google script data import when parsing an empty row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like data import to stop when parsing an empty row. I have tried this code but it still imports data past empty lines:

```
function readInAllData() {
var threads = GmailApp.search("subject:Report #7"); 
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[threads[0].getMessages().length-1];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
    attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Y input"); 
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
    var range = sheet.getRange("A:R");

    var row = 0;
          range.clearContent();
      for (var row=0; row<csvData.length; row++) {
          sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
            
                if (!csvData[row].join("")) break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You don't need a for loop to find the first empty row in your data. You can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to find the first row for which every cell is empty and then set the values up to this row:

```
const pos = csvData.findIndex(r => r.every(c=>c=='') );
sheet.getRange(1, 1, pos, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData.slice(0,pos));
```

**Solution:**

```
function readInAllData() {
var threads = GmailApp.search("subject:Report #7"); 
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[threads[0].getMessages().length-1];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
    attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Y input"); 
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
    var range = sheet.getRange("A:R");

    range.clearContent();
    const pos = csvData.findIndex(r => r.every(c=>c=='') );
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, pos, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData.slice(0,pos));
            
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Marios! The problem is that I would like to stop the data import when the first empty row appears. This empty row separates the data I want to import from the data I don't want to import. Below the empty row lies a long line of unwanted values that interferes with my calculated metrics on the Google Sheet.

Comment: @Snail Thanks for your feedback, I modified my answer. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: checked. Even after seeing instruction where that button should lie, it took two attempts to notice it.